# register_shutdown_function in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, error-handling

I'm trying to catch fatal errors occuring in my Zend Framework application. I tried to call register_shutdown_function from the bootstrap:

```
protected function _initErrorHandler()
{
    register_shutdown_function(array("My_ErrorHandler", 'shutdownHandler'));
}
```

Then, in My_ErrorHandler, I wrote a function :

```
<?php
class My_ErrorHandler
{
    static function shutdownHandler()
    {
        die('here');
    }
}
```

This doesn't work. I tried the same with set_error_handler, and it works. However, this last function can't catch fatal errors.

Do you what I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: This should have worked. Is there any chance that there are other shutdown handlers being attached? If yes and one of them terminates the script yours will never get the change to run.

Comment: As an experiment, place a function in the bootstrap where you are adding the register_shutdown_function, and change 'My_ErrorHandler' to $this. Does the function get called? If so, it may be that the class 'My_ErrorHandler' has not been loaded for some reason?

Comment: PHP > 5.2.3 perhaps try expressing argument for `callable` as 'MyClass::myCallbackMethod' instead of the array argument you are using.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to make it work.

In fact, it was working, but that was not very "friendly". The die('here') was hit, but after the fatal error was displayed in the browser.

So I catched the fatal error, and then redirected to the standard Zend Framework error controller, this is the result :

```
<?php
class My_ErrorHandler
{
    /** 
     * Catch all errors within the Applications
     * @see Bootstrap
     */ 
    static function shutdownHandler()
    {
        $e = error_get_last();
        if (!is_null($e) && $e['type'] == E_ERROR) { //fatal error

            //log
            Zend_Registry::get('log')->err($e['message']);

            //Redirect to error page
            $redirector = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Redirector();
            $redirector->gotoSimple('error', 'error', null, array('error_handler' => 'fatal'));
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it will help others ;)

Thanks to @Jon, @Richard Parnaby-King and @ficuscr for their help.

NB: try to keep shutdownHandler() as light as possible: it is called each page is displayed.