# How to avoid a white page with fatal php exception with Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I've seen this question asked and answered a few times but none of the solutions work for me. Also Zend Framework might complicate things here. I know the best solution is to fix the errors, but is there really no best practice to avoid a white page? I mean my code is pretty damn perfect, even tested sometimes, but nobody is perfect.
I've tried:

```
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
}
set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");
```

also

```
register_shutdown_function('forward_fatal');
function forward_fatal(){
    header("Location: index.html");
}
```

Still getting white page on fatal exception.

Comment: This might be helpful: [Register Shutdown Function in Zend Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051643/register-shutdown-function-in-zend-framework)

Answer (score 2):

1) read your log files

2) if your log files don't explain what went wrong then fix the error logging

3) in the *very* rare event where PHP crashed and core-dumped, then go find your core file and work out why it failed

4) don't write code with fatal errors in it

Comment: Can you elaborate on #3? My log file shows no errors related to this, but others so I know that logging is working. Also, I turned on errors in php and am still seeing a blank page, no errors, white page. Page source is empty as well.

Comment: The write a simple script which throws an exception and see if it's getting written to the logs. As to core files - that's a complicated question. where the file gets written, whether it gets written and what it's called depends on how the OS is configured